# The fastest way to normalize matrix by the sum of it rows

Tags: c++, optimization, x86, vectorization, intel-mkl

I have a matrix(or 2d array if you like) and I need to calculate the sum of it rows and then divide all matrix rows with this vector - the form of normalization. Currently, I am using MKL vsAdd routine to sum every row and then I am dividing every row in the matrix with MKL vsDiv by the sum that I got. This is the hottest point in my program. Any ideas how to optimize this using any tools? ( The size of matrix is 10 * 52)

Comment: take the inverse once and multiply each row.  Multiplication is *much* faster than division.  There might be other algorithmic changes you could make, I'm not sure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you do if the sum of rows is zero (e.g. due to a mix of positive and negative values)?      That aside, the calculation for a 10*52 matrix should not be much computation.   If it is a hotspot, that means you're doing it many times (e.g. within a loop).   Consider moving the "normalizing" (not a correct term for what you are doing, since normalizing usually only needs to be done once on a given vector, and values won't change after the first time throughj) outside the loops.

Comment: @Peter that is done many time - for all nodes and for many algorithm iterations. And this is the part of algorithm so it can't be moved. Also in every iteration I am doingmatrix multiplication of this matrix(sgemm).. and it is even faster then this "normalization" and sgem is harder operation.. so I think that my normalization is not optimal.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks a lot, this gave me +20%!